# Google Business Phone numbers?

Tags: seo, google

Is possible to have to different search results for phone numbers in google business, one phone number on the right hand side box and another under the top result?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking... Are you referring to [Google My Business](https://www.google.com/business/) local listings and the business information that appears in the [Google Knowledge Graph](http://www.optixsolutions.co.uk/blog/how-to-get-your-brand-appearing-on-the-right-of-google-search/)?

Comment: @zigojacko yes that is right, I didnt know the exact name for that... am I right, that there is not way to control what and where the numbers appear... ?

Comment: You can't control the layout of these no...

Answer (score 0):

The data elements you are talking about are populated from the Google Knowledge Graph. There is no way to control the phone numbers or other rich knowledge data being added in the way you are referring to. Generally speaking the same data that is at the top of the SERP will be added to the knowledge bar on the right hand side of the SERP and is simply shown in a different layout, sometimes with more data being shown on the right side knowledge box.